# 'Time.now' not showing the right time

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

I want to use `Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M")` to show the current time in my timezone, but it seems to be delayed for two hours. It shows: `28/08/2017 06:36` when it is `08:36`. How can I adjust the timezone to show the right time?

Comment: `Time.now.getlocal.zone` is this return you your zone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Pure Ruby Way:**

```
> Time.now.utc.localtime("+05:30").strftime("%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M")
#=> "28/08/2017  12:41"
```

where `+05:30` (IST) is the offset of the particular zone

**Note:** `Time.now.getlocal.zone` will return your local zone

---

Using **ActiveSupport**:

```
>  require 'active_support/time'
#=> true 
> Time.now.in_time_zone('US/Eastern').strftime("%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M")
#=> "28/08/2017  03:17"
```